# What is the Emacs keyboard shortcut for the Agda  symbol?

Tags: emacs, agda

I mean the list symbol in case it does not show up well in the title.

It is not `\bl` like the book says.

Comment: Have you put the code from the "Some Extra Emacs Definitions" section in your .emacs file?

Comment: Yeah, this is what I need. Only the copy/paste eats the newlines, so it would not be bad if somebody provided the definitions in text rather than pdf. I'll try to find it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [book](https://svn.divms.uiowa.edu/repos/clc/projects/agda/book/book.pdf) provides the code to make typing easier in the "Some Extra Emacs Definitions" addendum:

```
(eval-after-load "quail/latin-ltx"
   '(mapc (lambda (pair)
            (quail-defrule (car pair) (cadr pair) "TeX"))
           '( ("\\bb" "") ("\\bl" "") ("\\bs" "") ("\\bt" "") ("\\bv" "") ("\\cv" "⋎") ("\\comp" "○") ("\\m" "↦") ("\\om" "ω"))))
```

You just need to copy it from here and paste it into your .emacs file.

Comment: I should note that there are some more extras in the book.

Answer (score 1):

It's not part of the emacs mode yet but I have submitted a [Pull Request](https://github.com/agda/agda/pull/2305) to add the missing blackboard bold letters.

Answer (score 0):

Use `M-x` then `agda-input-show-translations` get a table of all the character bindings. Then you can use `C-s` to search for a specific character.

Comment: I got "Failing I-search:" for ``.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just typed in Emacs

```
\bL
```

, which gives me the blackboard bold font correctly. This is with agda 2.5.3 (installed via hackage per official documentation under Ubuntu 16.04)